# After refreshing the page, its contents disappear and an error appears

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I’m doing a project in which I get movie list by API. I wrote a code in which I output a list of these films on the page and when I click on one of them I come to the page which tells more details about this film. I did this using react-router-dom and when I go to the "about movie" page, the address looks like this: "http: // localhost: 8080/about/{movie name}". But if I refresh the page, then all the information disappears. I get this error in the console: "GET http: // localhost: 8080 / about / main.js net :: ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" As far as I understand this is due to the fact that when I refresh page the information that I get in props disappears. Can this be fixed with prevProps? And also the pictures in the page about movie didn't load anymore.

Route

```
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/about/:name" children={<ChooseFilm />} />
    </Switch>
```

FilmCards(Here I map and take out film list and also here link to the page about film).Link looks like this:

```
{this.props.listFilm.map((value,index)=>{
 let adressTitle = value.title.replace(/ /g,"-");// Got the name of the movie and replaced the spaces with -
 <Link to={{
    pathname: `/about/${adressTitle}`,// The path that is specified in Route
      state: {
           moreAboutFilm,     //
           filmPoster,        // I pass the parameters that I need on the page "about the movie" 
           filmId: value.id,  //
       }
 }}>
 </Link>
)})}
```

ChooseFilm

```
export default function ChooseFilm() {
    let {name} = useParams();
    let {state} = useLocation(); // I get the data that I transferred to Link and transferred to the page about the movie
  return (
        <About 
            moreAboutFilm={state.moreAboutFilm}
            filmPoster={state.filmPoster}
            filmId={state.filmId}
        />
  );
}
```

About (Here I process params which I get from Link and show information about the film.)

```
class About extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            detailsAboutFilm: [],
        }
    }


    filmDetails=()=>{
        fetch(this.props.moreAboutFilm)
        .then((moreDetails) => {
            return moreDetails.json(); 
        })
        .then((moreDetailsAboutFilm) => {
            let backgroundPath  = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${moreDetailsAboutFilm.backdrop_path}`;
            let detailsAboutFilm = [moreDetailsAboutFilm];
            this.setState({
                detailsAboutFilm,
                backgroundPath: backgroundPath
            }) 
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.filmDetails()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if (this.props.moreAboutFilm !== prevProps.moreAboutFilm) {
            this.filmDetails()
        }
    }
// And then when I received filmDetails I sort it with the help of map and display the information I need on the page.
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: shouldn't you be fetching film details like this `fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}')`, pls tell me if am missing something.

Comment: Please remove your API from the comment above. It is a secret, you should not share it with anyone.

Comment: Let me know if you are still having a problem fetching the data.

Comment: yes problem is still exist.When I on the page about film it's all right but when I refrsh page     all disappears and I have an error

Comment: You need to fetch by `id` not `name` to get the details for a film. TMDB does not support `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/name-of-the-movie` to get the movie details like this. It supports `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/334` the movieId in the end. If you still have problems let me know.

Comment: I change it but still the same problem.